# Jest - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

Doing some testing of some NodeJS functions using Jest, but it doesn't like `import` statements, e.g. `import DatabaseController from '../util/database-controller'`.

I've doing some reading and people suggested installing `babel-jest` and updating my config (below), but I've not had any luck. What am I missing? From what I understand, it doesn't understand `import` statements as it's an `es6` thing...

Jest part of my `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "<rootDir>/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Can you include what version of Babel-jest you're using? the update from 23 to 24 broke a lot of my regex for transforms. They switched to micromatch 3 in that update

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lately I find that I don't need `babel-jest` at all, and can get by simply with [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env), and the following `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-env"]]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually resolved this myself, but your answer is one of the issues I was having, so I'll mark it was correct :)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for my simple set-up:

devDependencies (in `package.json`):

```
  "devDependencies": {
      "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "jest": "^24.9.0",
      "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3"
    }
```

I simply created a `babel.config.js` as follows:

```
  // babel.config.js
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
```

*Note* - make sure to clear the cache before running!

Clear cache:

```
  ./node_modules/.bin/jest --clearCache
```